# what would be difference between while giving database name only "database" or "Database.db" in Sqlite

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am very new to android and I am working with Sqlite. while giving a database name I have small confusion

```
 private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "riturajsumn.db";

 private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "riturajsumn";
```

both above declaration work but I want to know what is the difference.

Comment: riturajsumn.db is SQlite DB file with specific extension while riturajsumn is simple SQLite DB file.

Comment: Basically no difference. You may call it whatever. Someone uses the extension `.sqlite`. The `.db` extension is the most commonly used.

Answer (score 1):

That database name is just a file name.

You can use any valid file name.
Extensions like `.db` or `.sqlite` or `.sq3` might help you later when you copy the file elsewhere, but the computer does not care.

Answer (score 1):

After doing Research I found difference like after inserting Value If I use **database name only "riturajsuman"** it does nt allow me to see SQL table and associate value
but when i use **database name "riturajsumn.db"** i can see the table and data in

DDMS:- file Exploler :- data: -data
but for that you will have to paste **com.questoid.sqlitemanager_1.0.0** jar in your Bundle:-eqlips:-dropins:-